# as for "Rules for Embedded Expressions", the string concatenation does not work

Tags: karate

I am fetching the data from database with SQL, I need pass a variable to the where clause, however, I find that the string concatenation doesn't work, even the official example

```
* def batchnum = "112344552"
* def getBatchIDSQL = '#("select id from sr_sendreceive where batchnum = " + batchnum)'
* print getBatchIDSQL
* def sendReceiveBatchid = db.readValue('#(getBatchIDSQL)')
```

Then, I tried the official example:

```
      # wrong !
      * def foo = 'hello #(name)'
      # right !
      * def foo1 = '#("hello " + name)'
      * print foo1

      * def name = 'test name'
      * def temp = 'hello ' + name
      * def foo2 = '#(temp)'
      * print foo2
```

**The result is :**

```
#("select id from sr_sendreceive where batchnum =" + batchnum)
#("hello " + name)
#(temp)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, the docs are wrong. This works for non-JSON only for `match`. Like this:

```
* def batchnum = "112344552"
* def actual = 'select id from sr_sendreceive where batchnum = 112344552'
* match actual == '#("select id from sr_sendreceive where batchnum = " + batchnum)'
```

Inside JSON it will work:

```
* def foo = { bar: '#("select id from sr_sendreceive where batchnum = " + batchnum)' }
* print foo
```

Thanks for pointing this out, I will update the docs.

Comment: Another case, my batchnum now is the format like this '0002d200-6d97-4228-97e4-8fffe1bf822d'. In the end, I need query data from mysql using this sql: select batchnum from sr_sendreceive where id = '0002d200-6d97-4228-97e4-8fffe1bf822d' , it failed and the id is truncated to '0002d200' .

Comment: @BitlinChen sorry that doesn’t make sense, ask a new question if needed - and please keep in mind Karate has nothing to do with SQL